# Overlapping and Rotated Images

Tags: css, tumblr

Is it possible for images to automatically overlap and rotate? For example [this website](http://www.bleachlondon.co.uk)

I've seen CSS transitions for single image rotations but not for a whole website. I'm using Tumblr

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Use css postion:absolute or position:relative. For more info, see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: I added - 
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-1deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-1deg);
    
The images are now tilted but I can't quite get them to overlap. Is it possible that all uploads automatically tilt and overlap? I can only see examples of creating divs for photosets

Comment: With position:absolute, use left: bottom: top: right: to position them. If they have different z-indices, they will overlap.

Comment: Without sounding like a total n00b... how do i set different z-indexes for them?

Comment: Do one with z-index:1 and one with z-index:2

Comment: But on Tumblr there is no option to make two different sections. All posts are listed as .posts .post.photo{